# use BIBINPUTS to specify other location for .bib file

Tags: bibtex, auxiliary-files

I'm trying to run bibtex from a different directory than my .bib file.  According to the description in 'man bibtex', I should be able to set the envirorment variable BIBINPUTS to include the location of my .bib file.  This is not working for me.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ # Mac OS X 10.7.4
$ bibtex -v
BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
$BIBINPUTS=/path/to/directory
$bibtex mypaper
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file thesis.bib
---line 62 of file mypaper.aux
: \bibdata{thesis
:                  }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file mypaper.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Hamlet"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "SP"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Lbook"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "companion"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "book"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Metafont"
```

I am certain that `thesis.bib` exists in `/path/to/directory`.

Is there any way I can verify directory `bibtex` is trying to read from?

Comment: Something like `kpsewhich -var-value BIBINPUTS`?  Also, don't you want to `export` your new value?

Comment: ah, I think I definitely want `export`. Thanks.  I'll give that a shot in about 30 min.  I've looked up `kpsewhich` too and I see how that can help be further troubleshoot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you @jon.

To use `BIBINPUTS` with bibtex, it must be exported to the environment passed to the child process.  So

```
$export BIBINPUTS=/path/to/directory
$bibtex mypaper
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add to use a `.bib` file 'in a non-standard area, outside your working directory' (or the equivalent).  The `kpsewhich -var-value BIBINPUTS` will let you see where `bibtex` expects to find `.bib` files.  (Not sure how/if that works on Windows....)

Comment: @jon In my case, the issue was that all my BibTeX files were in the directory `~/.bibtex/`.  However, the string `.bib` is removed (upper/lower case) from the list.  In general, also note that you need to include `.` in `$BIBINPUTS` if you (also) want to source files in the current directory.