# modifying .aux output \bibdata, using biblatex/bibtex8 with a build directory

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I want to use `biblatex` and I get got an error when using `bibtex8` (or other backend, doesn't matter). I already identified the problem: I am using a 'build' direcotry.

So my file stucture is:

```
myfile.tex
mybib.bib
/build [all copiled files go here, including myfile.aux and myfile-blx.bib]
```

in my `.tex` I have:

```
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

which produces the following in the `.aux` file:

```
\bibdata{myfile-blx,mybib}
```

now `bibtex8` is run from the base directory with (Texmaker):

```
bibtex8 --wolfgang build/%
```

it correctly finds the `.aux` file and the `mybib.bib` file but not the `-blx.bib` file.

I have three workarounds so far:

- not using a build directory so everything is in one directory (i don't like that)
- manually copy the `-blx.bib` file to the parent directory after running (pdf)latex
- manually editing the `.aux` file to: `\bibdata{build/myfile-blx,mybib}`

Obviously none of them desireable.

So how can I get this line in my `.aux` file automatically?

```
\bibdata{build/myfile-blx,mybib}
```

EDIT 2012-09-04:

@PLK: I would try to use `biber`. But I am working with this on two machines. And the main workstation is Windows 7 64 bit, and there is no binary for that on the biber homepage. And the 32 bit does not execute.

I am running on [Windows 7, 64 bit, miktex, texmaker, jabref] mainly and also on [xubuntu, 32 bit, texlive, texmaker, jabref].

I personaly think a minimal example is not that helpfull since everything compiles without any errors unless i'am using a build directory. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.8.1.
% Encoding: ISO8859_1

@ARTICLE{author2010,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {Fancy Title},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {91},
  pages = {229-261},
  number = {2},
  timestamp = {2012.09.01}
}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_review:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_publisher:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_author:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_journal:}

@comment{jabref-meta: selector_keywords:}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
Lots of text.
\footnote[111]{\cite[S.~250--255]{author2010}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

As said above everything runs without any error without a build dirctory. When I use a build directory the first `pdflatex` run works fine. And then `bibtex8` produces the following error/output in the `./build/myfile.blg` file:

```
The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf
The top-level auxiliary file: build/myfile.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
I couldn't open database file myfile-blx.bib
---line 4 of file build/myfile.aux
 : \bibdata{myfile-blx
 :                    ,mybib}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

This is because it expects `myfile-blx.bib` and `mybib.bib` to be both in the parent directory `./`. As stated above i can workaround by maually editig the `.aux` file before running `bibtex8`. When I do that it runs without errors.

Comment: Try using biber as the backend and see its `--outfile` and `--output_directory` options. Run `biber --help` to see what these do.

Comment: I edited the question with the requested information. As stated there there I run win7, 64 bit. And the `biber` binary form their website doesn't run

Comment: I tried again with downloading `biber`. This time it is runnable with the 32bit version on my 64 bit machine and doesn't crash. The `--output_directory` option does the trick! Thanks. Problem solved :D

Comment: Ok good, there is no 64bit version specifically as the 32bit should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The `--output_directory` option of biber deals with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `BIBINPUTS` environment variable from `bibtex` manpage.

In your case, the `bibtex` part of your compilation script could be:

```
export BIBINTPUTS=..
cd build
bibtex myfile
cd ..
```

I found this reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67205/use-bibinputs-to-specify-other-location-for-bib-file).